# Invalid UserLocation iPhone MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, mapkit

I am trying to set the mapView's center coordinate to be the users location:

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:[[[self mapView] userLocation] coordinate]];
```

However I am getting a crash which is to do with the user location being invalid:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Coordinate -180.00000000, -180.00000000'
```

Has anyone else had this error before? Or do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543571/how-to-check-validity-of-cllocation-in-ios.

Comment: This was posted a year before that question, therefore, that question is a duplicate of this. Nice try.

Comment: That comment was for new users (like I was when I faced this issue). The other thread has better solutions, the one here didn't work for me :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you need to get the `[[[[self mapView] userLocation] location] coordinate]` rather than the mapView's userLocation's coordinate.

Comment: Why - is this documented anywhere?